# Can't understand C construct in telegram-cli source code

Tags: c, telegram

I am browsing through telegram-cli source code to make some changes. However, I am stuck at a [syntax](https://github.com/vysheng/tgl/blob/ffb04caca71de0cddf28cd33a4575922900a59ed/updates.c#L809) that I am not able to understand.

```
#define user_cmp(a,b) (tgl_get_peer_id ((a)->id) - tgl_get_peer_id ((b)->id))
DEFINE_TREE(user, struct tgl_user *,user_cmp,0)

static void notify_status (struct tgl_user *U, void *ex) {
  struct tgl_state *TLS = ex;
  if (TLS->callback.user_status_update) {
    TLS->callback.user_status_update (TLS, U);
  }
}

static void status_notify (struct tgl_state *TLS, void *arg) {
  tree_act_ex_user (TLS->online_updates, notify_status, TLS);
  tree_clear_user (TLS->online_updates);
  TLS->online_updates = NULL;
  TLS->timer_methods->free (TLS->online_updates_timer);
  TLS->online_updates_timer = NULL;
}
```

The `tree_act_ex_user` function is not defined anywhere and IDE is navigating to second line i.e. `DEFINE_TREE(user, struct tgl_user *,user_cmp,0)`. Please explain or point to a reference what construct is this?

Comment: https://github.com/vysheng/tgl/blob/master/tree.h#L133

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what construct is this?

A macro expansion that defines a function. A reduced example:

```
#define DEFINE_TREE(NAME, some_arg, some_arg2, yet_another_arg) \
static void tree_act_ex_##NAME() { \
     do_something(); \
}

DEFINE_TREE(some_string, arg1, arg2, arg3)
// expands to:
// static void tree_act_ex_some_string() { do_something(); }

int main() {
    tree_act_ex_some_string();
}
```